# Separate drupal view filters from the results

Tags: views, search

I implemented a search index using Drupal Search API, and then created a view using that search index. In my view I added filters on searchable fields. My search is working very well.

However, my clients want to have the search filter controls in the sidebar and the search results in the main content region. But my filter controls and results are part of a single view. It is possible to separate them?

**Drupal version : 7.26**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the Drupal Search API but if you are creating a View with exposed filters, you can have them put in a Block instead of being part of the View.  Then you can put that Block anywhere you want.  To do this, you go into the Advanced Settings of your View:

[image]

and in **Exposed form in block:** select `Yes` instead of the default `No.`  Then you can go into the Block UI and place the newly created block wherever you want.

One interesting effect:  If you don't restrict this block to the page of the View in the Block UI, it will show up on all pages, and if your users then select any of the filters in it and hit apply, that will take them to the View page and results.